# Implementation of WebApplicationInitializer not loaded from library jar

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, classpath

I have the following project structure:

```
root
|---- web_1 (war)
|
|---- web_2 (war)
|
|---- common-security (jar)
|
|---- ear_1 (war_1 + common-security)
|
|---- ear_2 (war_2 + common-security)
```

In this **common-security**, I have added dependency of `org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.9.RELEASE`.

This is a sample implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` which present in **common-security**:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class MySecureWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("m");
    }
}
```

Each **ear** contain a **war** file and the **common-security** jar. The **common-security** jar is added in the Class-Path in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of the **war** module. Each of the **war** file contains `web.xml` and my servlet version is 3.1.

When I hit the landing page I see:

`No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`

But if I duplicate the implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` in any **war** module and remove the dependency of **common-security**, from that module I see it detects one `WebApplicationInitializer` and logs the designated message.

I need to have one common module of spring and security which will be used by two different wars.

Any pointer would be great.